# looking for clean PHP code editor

Tags: php, ide, editor

I've been using Dreamweaver for a long time but it has many features I don't need. I would like a clean simple editor like textmate but I use Windows..

I tried Zend Studio but as DW it has many features I don't need.

What other editor would you recommend for HTML, PHP, CSS, and JS?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, is it?

Comment: Then what features do you need?

Comment: @Gumbo just a simple interface and a window for file browsing.

Comment: Then why don’t you write that? By the way: Do you already [E TextEditor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) that is more or less a clone of TextMate for Windows?

Comment: yes I tried it. I don't like the interface tho. Doesn't resemble textmate much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally love [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) - nice, clean interface and options for different highlighting/formatting depending on what kind of code you're writing (it supports a lot right out of a fresh install, including HTML, CSS, JS and PHP).

One thing it lacks is the Visual Studio Intellisense-esque/autocomplete - depends what you need/don't need, I guess.

Comment: What I especially like about Notepag++ is that it is fast. It isn't some big IDE like Eclipse or Zend that needs half an hour to load.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) from Jetbrains. It supports everything you need in a single package. Here is a [recent review](http://inchoo.net/tools/phpstorm-ide-overview/) of PhpStorm. Also, if you want super light PHP editing you could go with Notepad ++ and take a look at [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) which is a like a PHP-less subset to PhpStorm designed to handle HTML, JavaScript, CSS etc.

Quote:

> The guys at JetBrains did this
>   application (and WebStorm) with
>   developer in mind from start to
>   finish. Even now, they keep focused on
>   their work to make this app a
>   developer’s extension rather than just
>   a product to sell.

Comment: +1 for amazing editor :)

Comment: Great company. Many amazing products.

Comment: +1 After reading this I switched to PhpStorm and found it *awesome*!

Answer (score 2):

> What other editor would you recommend for HTML, PHP, CSS, and JS?

The [Zeus editor](http://www.zeusedit.com) does the standard *code folding* and *syntax highlighting* for these languages.

But Zeus does a few other things like *HTML Validation*, *Zen Coding* and it is also fully scriptable in Java Script.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something dead simple, I've used [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) for quite some times when I had Windows. (Check out the [extras](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEExtras.html) also.) Now, on Linux, I use [GEdit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/) :)

Comment: +1 fpr Scintilla/SciTE.
Its Sci'n'tilla BTW :-)

Answer (score 1):

I just converted from Dreamweaver to Eclipse for PHP. Still has the code suggestion but much cleaner management of projects.

Answer (score 0):

I up-voted Notepad++ because it's my favorite free text editor, but if you don't mind spending a few bucks (USD 60) I've used UltraEdit for many years and would recommend it for any language.  Customer support has been awesome.

http://www.ultraedit.com/

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ might be the best option for Windows users since it's robust and free. However, since you did not specify your OS, I can assume that you might have Linux or OS X.

With that said, I can suggest [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda) as a good alternative to Dreamweaver just because it's very robust and yet is still very simplistic.

It's not free, but it's allot cheaper than Dreamweaver.

Sadly, it's only available on OS X.

Another application that I like is Aptana (http://www.aptana.com) and this one is available free on Windows, Linux and OS X. It might not be as simplistic, but it's a great application for editing. I personaly prefer Aptana over Notepa

Answer (score 0):

I've been using PHPEdit for years. It is a very nice PHP IDE that also has some nice features to manage MySQL databases.

Answer (score 0):

> EmEditor

is another great PHP editor and maybe another scripting language and multi purpose text editor that have great features. Lightweight and fast, one of nice feature is vertical selection editing.

http://www.emeditor.com/